# PowerShell: Use Get-Content from multiple text files to send a message

Tags: powershell

There was very little on the topic of using multiple text files for PowerShell, only found stuff that would take one list and run it against the primary list.  Anyway...

My question comes from a need to combine 2 sets of data, equal in the number of rows.
Server.txt & SessionID.txt.  Both files are created from another Get-XASession query.
I wanted to combine these in a Send-XAMessage.

> Servers.txt = "Server1","Server2","Server3",etc.
>
> SessionIds.txt = "2","41","18",etc.

Here's the code I've tried unsuccessfully...
BTW, "ServerX", is a static connection server required for XA Remote computing.

> $Server = Get-Content .\Server.txt
>
> $SessionIds = Get-Content .\SessionIds.txt
>
> ForEach ($s in $Servers -And $i in $SessionIds) {
> Send-XASession -ComputerName ServerX -ServerName $s -SessionId $i -MessageTitle "MsgTitle" -MessageBody "MsgBody" }

For normal usability, we can switch the Stop-XASession, with Get-Service, and use the $s for -ComputerName.
And switch SessionId for -ServiceName.

That would look something like this...

> ForEach ($s in $Servers -And $i in $Sevices) { Get-Service -ComputerName $s -Name $i } | FT Name,Status

- The only thing that matters, is that each line on both text files is ran through simultaneously.  **No duplicates**.  Matching line 1 in Servers.txt to line 1 on SessionIds.txt and using it in each command.
  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$Server = Get-Content .\Server.txt

$SessionIds = Get-Content .\SessionIds.txt

$i=0

ForEach ($s in $Servers)

 { 
   Send-XASession -ComputerName ServerX -ServerName $s -SessionId $SessionIds[$i++] -MessageTitle "MsgTitle" -MessageBody "MsgBody" 
}
```

That will cycle the $SessionIds elements in synch with the $server elements.  The postincrement operator on $SessionIds[$i++] will increment $i each time it goes through the loop.

Comment: Ingenious idea to index the text file, but now I'm getting an error...
Error:
Cannot index into a null array.

Comment: I even tried to set "_$i=1_", still no go, same error msg.

Comment: Ok, so I'm still learning...
Was missing a closing '"' parenthesis on the MessageBody.  
This solution works beautifully, Thank you.